# Считать блок из файла не загружаю весь файл в память

Tags: c#, .net

Всем привет. Подскажите как сделать? Проблема такая. Нужно считать файл заданными блоками. Использую для этого  `FileStream.Read` и он считывает файл блоками, и постепенно загружая его в память. А хотелось, что бы он читая каждый новый блок, выполнял с ним что-нибудь и забывал его, не храня то что прочитал ранее. Подскажите как это можно сделать? Так же как сделать так, что бы чтение началось с указанной позиции например с 3/4 или 1/2 файла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Узрите мощь [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filestream.seek(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public override long Seek(
long offset,
SeekOrigin origin)
```

Можно указать смещение в байтах от начала файла.

Вызывать вот так:

```
 fs.Seek(100500, SeekOrigin.Begin);  //указать потоку,
                                     // что дальше будем читать 
                                     //байты, отступив 100500 
                                     //байт от начала файла
 fs.Read... //читать
```